# Implement docker mongodb replica set config settings inside .yml file

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, config, replicaset, rs

I have set a MongoDB replica set which is running properly.
But I want to run the config settings inside the .yml, and not initiating inside a replica set node.

by config settings I mean:

1.

```
config = {
  "_id": "comments",
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "host": "node1:27017"
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "host": "node2:27017"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "host": "node3:27017"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the below:

2.

```
rs.initiate(config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out a way, hope it helps.Below i will post my .yml file, rsinit file and rs.sh file, all the file should be placed on the same location in order to work, rest all config are written anyways.

.yml file:

version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: localmongo1
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]
    # volumes:
    #   - /data/db/mongotest:/data/db # This is where your volume will persist. e.g. VOLUME-DIR = ./volumes/mongodb

mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: localmongo2
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]

mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: localmongo3
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]

rsinit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: rsinit
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "rs.sh"]

rsinit(normal text file):

FROM mongo

ADD rs.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rs.sh

rs.sh file:

## !/bin/bash

echo "prepare rs initiating"

check_db_status() {
  mongo1=$(mongo --host mongo1 --port 27017 --eval "db.stats().ok" | tail -n1 | grep -E '(^|\s)1($|\s)')
  mongo2=$(mongo --host mongo2 --port 27017 --eval "db.stats().ok" | tail -n1 | grep -E '(^|\s)1($|\s)')
  mongo3=$(mongo --host mongo3 --port 27017 --eval "db.stats().ok" | tail -n1 | grep -E '(^|\s)1($|\s)')
  if [[ $mongo1 == 1 ]] && [[ $mongo2 == 1 ]] && [[ $mongo3 == 1 ]]; then
    init_rs
  else
    check_db_status
  fi
}

init_rs() {
  ret=$(mongo --host mongo1 --port 27017 --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: 'mongo1:27017' }, { _id: 1, host: 'mongo2:27017' }, { _id: 2, host: 'mongo3:27017' } ] })" > /dev/null 2>&1)
}

check_db_status > /dev/null 2>&1

echo "rs initiating finished"
exit 0